# Java Priority queue to sort integer inputs

Tags: java, sorting, input, priority-queue

I'm trying to sort a sequence of positive integers which are inputted by the user with the use of Priority Queue. I'm not sure how to implement something so I'm wondering if anyone could help.This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class priorityquene implements Comparable<priorityquene> 
    {
        final int priority;
        final String name;

        public priorityquene(int p, String n) 
        {
            priority = p;
            name = n;
        }

        public String toString() 
        {
            return priority + ", " + name;
        }

        public int compareTo(priorityquene other) 
        {
            return priority < other.priority ? -1 : priority > other.priority ? 1 : 0;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            PriorityQueue<priorityquene> pq = new PriorityQueue<priorityquene>();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");
            int num1 = input.nextInt();
            pq.add(new priorityquene(num1, " "));
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");
            int num2 = input.nextInt();
            pq.add(new priorityquene(num2, " "));
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");
            int num3 = input.nextInt();
            pq.add(new priorityquene(num3, " "));
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");
            int num4 = input.nextInt();
            pq.add(new priorityquene(num4, " "));
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");
            int num5 = input.nextInt();
            pq.add(new priorityquene(num5, " "));

            while (!pq.isEmpty())
                System.out.println(pq.remove());
        }
    }
```

There are some things I'm not sure how to implement.
How do i set it to accept an unlimited inputs and when a specific integer is input, say 0; it begins to sort from smallest to highest the inputs so far prior to 0?

Comment: Have you learned about loops?

Comment: Are you asking how to do your inputs in a loop, instead of as 5 separate cycles of `println/nextInt/pq.add` ?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how can i add inputs while in a loop.

Comment: Most code works the same inside a loop as it does outside.  Have you looked around for examples of reading input within a loop?  There are dozens right here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your `priorityqueue` class is not a priority queue. It is an *element* of a priority queue. The real priority queue is `pq`. Don't misname classes.

Answer (score 0):

To get re prompted for input try the following:

```
int num;
do {
  System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");
  num = input.nextInt();
  pq.add(new priorityquene(num, " "));
} while (num > 0)
```

Comment: Almost.  The only issue with this is that the final 0 gets added to the queue.  Ideally, you'd want to escape in the middle of the loop, not at the end.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i set it to accept an unlimited inputs

In a loop.

> and when a specific integer is input, say 0; it begins to sort from smallest to highest the inputs so far prior to 0?

Priority queues don't work that way. They do a partial ordering every time you add something to them, and they repeat that every time you remove something. If you mean you want to *display* the PQ, just remove and print the first entry repeatedly while there is one when 0 is entered.

You shouldn't name your own class `priorityqueue` given that you're using `java.util.PriorityQueue.` It just causes confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a "forever" loop with a `return`, off in its own method.

```
private static void enqueueNumbersFromScanner(Scanner input, PriorityQueue pq) {
    for (;;) {  
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");
        int response = input.nextInt();
        if (response == 0) {
            return;
        }
        pq.add(new priorityquene(response, " "));
    }
}
```

Then, inside your `main`, just write

```
enqueueNumbersFromScanner(input, pq);
```